# Adjective for something getting on your nerves

Tags: word-choice

What is the equivalent adjective we could use for something/somebody getting on your nerves? It's not annoyed, as this is usually by something physical (or at least I think so), it's not nervous as nervousness is perceived as something different to being pissed off, agitated/upset I feel have a different meaning than "get on one's nerves".

The closest I can think to it is "being pissed off". Is there a more formal word for somebody getting on your nerves / pisses you off?

For example you wouldn't say to your boss that a colleague is pissing you off, or that they get on your nerves. You can always phrase it somehow else like "they are not being co-operative", but I would like to know if there's a formal adjective for it.

Comment: I disagree that annoyance has to be caused by something physical. You could say "I find X's behaviour annoying/irritating/exasperating."

Comment: Quite possibly a duplicate of [word or phrase for someone who annoys you as soon as they walk in and start talking](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150294/word-or-phrase-for-someone-who-annoys-you-as-soon-as-they-walk-in-and-start-talk/324791#324791).

Answer (score 1):

There are several adjectives you could use: "vexatious", "irritating" and "pesky" come to mind.

It seems your colleague is **irritating**.

> irritating (adj) -  "causing displeasure, anger, or annoyance. an irritating noise/habit"
>
> "I felt more and more angry. There was something very irritating and aggressive in Summerlee's demeanour."  [**MW**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irritating)

- he's irritating
- he has an irritating habit
- he irritates me
- I'm irritated by his stupidity.

Answer (score 1):

The word that immediately came to mind for me was `irksome`.  While it's fairly close to annoying I think it is often used instead of annoying when you want to indicate that it's a more temporary state.

With respect to "they are not being co-operative", I think `disagreeable` or `contrary` could both be applicable as they more directly indicate that you are having trouble reaching common ground with them and not necessarily that you dislike their personality.

Although that may be more in the case of phasing it as "being irksome/disagreeable/contrary", which becomes more of a phrase but is definitely better than just calling someone disagreeable, for example, which might be taken as a more general statement about your feelings toward them.

Answer (score 0):

bothersome

> adjective
>   1. causing annoyance or worry; troublesome.
>  [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bothersome)
>
> bother
>  verb
>   1. To cause to be irritated, especially by repeated acts; trouble or annoy
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bother)

There's nothing wrong with using "annoying", it's pretty much the same thing as many other suggestions here.

> "Go bother/annoy someone else." -- Can't see much difference between
>   these.